# Can't print out function result in Python

Tags: python, string, function, integer

I'm new to Python and after going through an example using a function to raise a number to a specific exponent, I tried to have it as the user for the numbers instead of just inputting them into the code.

Below is what I have:

```
def raise_to_power(base_num, pow_num):
    int(base_num)
    int(pow_num)
    result = 1
    for index in range(pow_num):
        result = result * base_num2

    return result


base_num = input("What number would you 
like to exponentially raise?: ")

pow_num = input("To what power?: ")

print(raise_to_power(base_num, pow_num))`
```

When I try to run it though, I get the error listed below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/PycharmProjects/Exponent 
Function.py", line 17, in <module>
print(raise_to_power(base_num, pow_num))
File "C:/Users/PycharmProjects/Exponent 
Function.py", line 7, in raise_to_power
for index in range(pow_num):
TypeError: 'str' object cannot be 
interpreted as an integer
```

Could someone explain why this might be happening?

Thank you,

Comment: convert string input to integer.

Comment: hint: google the error message before you post a question, this has been asked and answered 100s of times.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I read inputs as numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20449427/how-can-i-read-inputs-as-numbers)

Comment: `pow_num = int(pow_num)`

Answer (score 0):

`int(base_num)` doesn't change the argument. To convert the `base_num` to string and save into the same variable use:

```
base_num = int(base_num)
```

This code sample shows some weaknesses of the design: why should `base_num` be of the string type initially. Try to call the variables with more meaningful names that would avoid this confusion.

Answer (score 0):

your conversion of input string to integer is not correct.

### Try the below code:

```
def raise_to_power(base_num, pow_num):  
    result = 1
    for index in range(int(pow_num)):
        result = result * int(base_num)
    return result
```

Answer (score 0):

You did two mistake.
1- int(base_num) is not good way to type casting.
2- In method you are passing base_num but in for loop you are using base_num2.
Here is the correct code.

```
def raise_to_power(base_num, pow_num):
    result=1
    for index in range(int(pow_num)):
        result = result * int(base_num)
    return result
base_num = input("What number would you")
pow_num = input("To what power?: ")
print(raise_to_power(base_num, pow_num))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def raise_to_power(base_num, power_num):

    result = 1

    for index in range(power_num):
        result = result * base_num

    return result 
          
base_num = input("enter a base number you want : ")
power_num = input("enter the power of base number : ")

print(str(raise_to_power(int(base_num), int(power_num))))
```

Comment: Please consider an [edit] to your answer to explain how it solves the OPs problem and how it improves upon previous answers.

Comment: i am new to this community, thank you @DavidBuck for guide me